# Reading columns in pandas with lists to create new categorical columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a column of strings that looks like this

```
col_1
Spiderman
Abe Lincoln
Superman
Ghandi
Jane Austin
Robert de Niro
Elon Musk
George Bush
Bill Gates
Barak Obama
Anne Frank
```

I have manually gone through the column and made lists of categories for these characters:

```
l1 = [ 'Abe Lincoln', 'George Bush', 'Barak Obama']
l2 = ['Spiderman', 'Superman']
l3 = ['AnneFrank', 'Ghandi']
```

I have made a dict of these lists

```
dict = {'l1': l1, 'l2': l2,'l3': l3} #and so on
```

what I want to do is make a new column by reading column 1 and returns a number depending on the which list the str(cell) appears in; so the output would be

```
 col_1            col2
Spiderman          2
Abe Lincoln        1
Superman           2
Ghandi             3
Jane Austin        4
Robert de Niro     4
Elon Musk          4
George Bush        1
Bill Gates         4
Barak Obama        1
Anne Frank         3
```

I'm just not sure how to put use the lists and dicts in a defined function with an if/else, I'm not even sure if I need the dict but I think I do.

I have tried something like

```
def group(x, dict):
    for key, value in dict:
        if x in key:
             return 1
        else:
             return 0
```

data["group"] = data.col1.apply(group)

now I know the above code won't work (because it's nonsense) but I have used a function similar to this to categorise a gender column before, however, I can't seem to get my head around the code for this one.

As always, thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: `df['col'].isin()`

Comment: Apologies for naming the dict "dict" it was just a name I haven't done in my actual code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need loop by dictionary and set values of `key`s with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check membership - in sample data get `NaN`s, because missing another values in dict:

```
#not use python reserved word dict for variable name
d = {'l1': l1, 'l2': l2,'l3': l3} 

for k, v in d.items():
    df.loc[df['col_1'].isin(v), 'new'] = k
print (df)
             col_1  new
0        spiderman   l2
1      Abe Lincoln   l1
2         superman   l2
3           Ghandi   l3
4      Jane Austin  NaN
5   Robert de Niro  NaN
6        Elon Musk  NaN
7      George Bush   l1
8       Bill Gates  NaN
9      Barak Obama   l1
10      Anne Frank  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Restructure your `dict` and use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html).

N.B. I renamed `dict` to `my_dict` for this example. It is a bad idea use use 'dict' as the name.

```
remapped_dict = {i: k for k, v in my_dict.items() for i in v}

df['col_2'] = df['col_1'].map(remapped_dict).str.extract(r'(\d+)')
```

[out]

```
             col_1 col_2
0        Spiderman     2
1      Abe Lincoln     1
2         Superman     2
3           Ghandi     3
4      Jane Austin   NaN
5   Robert de Niro   NaN
6        Elon Musk   NaN
7      George Bush     1
8       Bill Gates   NaN
9      Barak Obama     1
10      Anne Frank   NaN
```

Comment: I really like this answer but when I run it I just get NaN in the new column.

Comment: @KevOMalley743, you will get `NaN` for any value that does not exist in any of your lists `l1`, `l2`, `l3` etc. Have you checked that the name in `col_1` exists in one ofyour lists where there is a NaN output?

Comment: I found and and tried this again having just droppedna() and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Flatten your `dict` then we do `map` , also do not name your dict as `dict`

```
from functools import reduce

yourd = reduce(lambda a, b: dict(a, **b), [dict.fromkeys(y,x) for x , y in d.items()])
df['New']=df.col_1.map(yourd)
df
Out[194]: 
             col_1  New
0        Spiderman   l2
1      Abe Lincoln   l1
2         Superman   l2
3           Ghandi   l3
4      Jane Austin  NaN
5   Robert de Niro  NaN
6        Elon Musk  NaN
7      George Bush   l1
8       Bill Gates  NaN
9      Barak Obama   l1
10      Anne Frank  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution along the same lines

```
def func(x):
    if x in l1:
        return 1
    if x in l2:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3

df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(func)
```